# C# using Generics both in the Interface and its implementor class

Tags: c#, generics, interface

I want to create an interface that works for all the IComparable types. For example

```
public interface SortAlgorithm<T> where T : System.IComparable<T>
{
    List<T> Sort(List<T> input);
}
```

And I want its implementors to be generic as well with the same specification I provide in the interface. Like the example below

```
public class InsertionSort<T> : SortAlgorithm<T>
```

Here is my purpose for doing this. I want all my sorting algorithms to work with all types that implements the IComparable interface. And want to provide the specification that the T is a subclass of IComparable once in the interface. But when I do this, I get the following error.

Error   1   The type 'T' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'Algorithms.SortingAlgorithm.SortAlgorithm'. There is no boxing conversion or type parameter conversion from 'T' to 'System.IComparable'.

I did not understand the reason for this. I can implement a generic interface and make its implementor classes generic as well but I can't do the same when give a specification in the interface (where T : System.IComparable)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

All derived generic classes will also have to implement the generic constraint.

Therefore, you should declare the class as:

```
public class InsertionSort<T> : SortAlgorithm<T> where T : System.IComparable<T>
```

What the error basically says is that the generic parameter `T` (which at this point can be any class or struct) is not guaranteed to implement `IComparable<T>`, as constrained by the base class (the `SortAlgorithm` interface).

You can provide this guarantee by specifying the constraint on the `InsertionSort` class as well, as presented above.

Comment: Won't using `T : IComparable<T>` create some problem? Shouldn't it be `T : IComparable<U>`?

Comment: @LightStriker No, I don't see any problem with that.

Comment: @wOlf: T is IComparable<T>... So T is IComparable<IComparable<...>>?

Comment: @LightStriker It's not unusual for a class `T` to implement `IComparable<T>`. All that does is make implement a `int CompareTo(T other)` method.

Comment: There are many examples of this in the BCL (especially primitive types). See for example: `Byte`, `Char`, `String`, all the ints etc.

Comment: @wOlf: Talking about the constraint, not the implementation. You constraint `T` to be `IComparable<T>`. Would that make `T` into  `IComparable<IComparable<IComparable<...>>>`. Should it be `T : IComparable<U>` to prevent the generic of IComparable from being forced into being a IComparable too? Or am I overthinking the relationship between the constraint and the generic?

Comment: @LightStriker No, the constraint forces `T` to be `IComparable<T>`, not `IComparable<IComparable<T>>`

Comment: @wOlf: So `T` of the constraint is not the same as the `T` in the `IComparable`?

Comment: Yes, it's the same. You can see `T : IComparable<T>` as saying "Class `T` should provide a way for it's instances to be compared." That way is the method I mentioned above.

Comment: @wOlf: Good grief... Think we don't understand each other. I know the goal is to constraint T to be derived from IComparable, but is `T : IComparable<T>` the same thing as `T : IComparable<U>`?

Comment: @LightStriker `U` is not a defined generic parameter?  Where does this `U` come from?

Comment: @Servy: I know it's not defined. But I find this syntax very weird, as `T` is already defined to be constraint to `IComparable`. Why would the generic type inside `IComparable` also be `T`? Shouldn't it be described as `IComparable` with no information about in the inner generic type or defined as another generic type that may or not be constraint to `IComparable`? My mind somehow sees a weird recursive constraint of type `T`.

Comment: @LightStriker No, there's no recursion. Use DotPeek or a similar decompilation tool and look at how `Byte` implements `IComparable<Byte>` and everything will be clear. You can also try to write an example yourself.

Comment: @LightStriker [Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/03/curiouser-and-curiouser.aspx) is a somewhat longer explanation, rather than me trying to fit something into a comment.

Comment: @Servy: That is a very awesome article. Thanks a lot.